# How to denote matrix concatenation?

Tags: matrices, notation, block-matrices

Trivial question: Is there any standard notation for the concatenation of two or more matrices?

**Example:**

$$A = \left(\begin{array}[c c] 
- a_1 & a_2\\
a_3 & a_4
 \end{array}\right),$$

$$B = \left(\begin{array}[c c] 
- b_1 & b_2\\
b_3 & b_4
 \end{array}\right),$$

Then the concatenation (by rows) of $A$ and $B$ is:

$$C = \left(\begin{array}[c c] 
- a_1 & a_2\\
a_3 & a_4 \\
 b_1 & b_2\\
b_3 & b_4
 \end{array}\right).$$

I just want to know if there is a standard notation for this operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such a thing as "augmenting" two matrices. For example, augmenting your matrices $A$ and $B$ above gives $$(A\mid B)=\left(\begin{array}{ll}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{array}\left|\begin{array}{ll}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\end{array}\right.\right).$$ This is useful notation for Gaussian row reduction since it makes clear the two matrices.

You can also write $[\begin{array}{l}A& B\end{array}]$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this usually denoted as $(A\vert B)$? In my case the dimensions of the matrices of interest are of the order of hundreds.

Comment: Yes, usually you would write the augmentation as $(A|B)$ or simply as a block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A & B \end{bmatrix}$. If you want to indicate the dimensionality, you could also do: $\begin{bmatrix}A_{(k\times m)} & B_{(k\times n)} \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Answer updated with comments in mind.

Comment: I find it interesting the way you seem to make a distinction between square and round brackets for matrix notation, is that distinction spelt out somewhere in a text book? It is not something that's standard I think.

Comment: I've seen both styles used; I guess it may depend on the field.

Answer (score 6):

In the example given,
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}
$$
is a standard notation. This is a particular example of "block notation".